# Using document.write in one HTML file to write into another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

Is it possible to use document.write in one HTML file to write into another HTML file?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. You should give details

Comment: the problem with this question is that document.write does not write in any file.

Comment: document.write writes in the place you call it, you should really try to avoid it as much as possible, there are much better and cleaner way to update data using javascript.

Comment: `document.write` does not write to any html file. It adds content to the current document object loaded in the browser tab from where it is run.

Comment: @techfoobar: Not necessarily the same window, you can write to a window using script in another window, as long as you don't run afoul of the SOP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, that's right. You can basically do `anyDocumentObject.write(...)` where `anyDocumentObject` can be in any window object the caller has access to..

Answer (score 3):

`document.write` doesn't write to files, it writes to documents in windows in the browser. You can use `document.write` in a script included in one page to write to another, like this:

```
var wnd = window.open("about:blank");
wnd.document.write("Hi there");
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ayuruf/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ayuruf/1/edit)

...which creates a new window and writes output to it (you have to do this within the handler of a user-generated event, or the popup will get blocked by most browsers).

You can also do this with an existing window if you know its name, because `window.open` will give you access to the existing window (assuming all of this is on the same origin and so the SOP doesn't apply):

```
var wnd = window.open("", "knownWindowName");
wnd.document.write("More content for the existing window");
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/erukaj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/erukaj/1/edit)

`document.write` is a fairly antiquated (and, I believe, deprecated in HTML5) way to generate content, though, long since mostly superceded by using the DOM. Some references:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)
- [DOM3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)
- [Other DOM Specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)

You may wish to use a godo library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), as they provide a great deal of utility functionality on top of the DOM and help smooth over some browser quirks/differences/bugs.